# Want to add a small icon in the corner of a product Picture

Tags: image, products

I want to be able to add a small picture into the corner of products that are within a certain category. For example I have a Featured products category which is used on my home page to display certain products. However i want to add a small image to the corner of these products so customers know they are Featured products even when the find the products in there own categories.

If i havnt explained myself very well please just let me know and i will try explain my problem better.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cat= $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryId = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat[0])->getId();
if($categoryId){
//add code for image here
<img src="" >

}
```

Comment: where do i add this, sorry iam rather new to magento

Comment: Wherever your product image is coming from, featured.phtml I guess

Comment: In the .phtml that generate the product items on your home page, if I read your question right.

Comment: ok thanks guys i will have a play around and try find the right place for it within the file. Thank you